# Linearised diffeomorphisms on arbitrary gravitational background Part 1

Tags: gravity, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

Consider some spacetime $\big(\mathcal{M},g_{\mu\nu}\big)$ parameterised by local coordinates $x^{\mu}$ ($\mathcal{M}$ is a smooth differentiable manifold equipped with a Lorentzian metric $g_{\mu\nu}$). Under an infinitesimal change of coordinates $x^{\mu}\rightarrow x'^{\mu}=x^{\mu}-\xi^{\mu}$, to first order in $\xi^{\mu}$ the metric transforms according to
\begin{align}
\delta_{\xi}g_{\mu\nu}:= g'_{\mu\nu}(x) - g_{\mu\nu}(x
) =  \nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+ \nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu}~. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Here $\nabla_{\mu}$ is the torsion-free and metric compatible covariant derivative.

We wish to perform a pertubative expansion about some fixed background metric $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$
\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu}=\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu} \tag{2}
\end{align}
where equation (2) defines $h_{\mu\nu}=h_{\nu\mu}$ (i.e. holds to all orders) and the inverse metric will be an infinite series in $h_{\mu\nu}$.

To first order in $\xi^{\mu}$ I have shown that equation (1) is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\delta_{\xi}g_{\mu\nu} = \delta_{\xi} \bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+\delta_{\xi} h_{\mu\nu}= \bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+ \bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} +\mathcal{L}_{\xi}h_{\mu\nu}~.\tag{3}
\end{align}
Here $\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}$ is the (torsion-free, metric compatible) covariant derivative for the background $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$, I have used $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ to raise/lower indices and $\mathcal{L}_{\xi}$ is the Lie derivative along $\xi^{\mu}$,
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_{\xi}h_{\mu\nu}=\xi^{\rho}\partial_{\rho}h_{\mu\nu}+\partial_{\mu}\xi^{\rho}h_{\rho\nu}+\partial_{\nu}\xi^{\rho}h_{\mu\rho}=\xi^{\rho}\bar{\nabla}_{\rho}h_{\mu\nu}+\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi^{\rho}h_{\rho\nu}+\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi^{\rho}h_{\mu\rho}~. \tag{4}
\end{align}

**Question**

If (4) is correct then I believe there should be another way to arrive at it, which goes as follows. We Denote the Christoffel symbols for $g_{\mu\nu}$ by $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}$ and those for $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ by $\bar{\Gamma}_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}$. Then, to first order in $\xi^{\mu}$ (and probably also in $h_{\mu\nu}$ since $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}$ includes the inverse metric) the decomposition (2) means we will have $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}=\bar{\Gamma}_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}+\delta \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}$. To first order we should be able to compute $\delta\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}$ by means of the Palantini identity
\begin{align}
\delta\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\sigma}\big(\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}h_{\nu\sigma}+\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}h_{\mu\sigma}+\bar{\nabla}_{\sigma}h_{\mu\nu}\big) \approx \frac{1}{2}\bar{g}^{\rho\sigma}\big(\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}h_{\nu\sigma}+\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}h_{\mu\sigma}+\bar{\nabla}_{\sigma}h_{\mu\nu}\big) ~.\tag{5}
\end{align}
However, upon applying this identity I find instead that
\begin{align}
\delta_{\xi}g_{\mu\nu} &=  \bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+ \bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} + \xi^{\rho}\bar{\nabla}_{\rho}h_{\mu\nu}-\xi^{\rho}\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}h_{\rho\nu}-\xi^{\rho}\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}h_{\mu\rho}\\
&= \bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+ \bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} + \xi^{\rho}\bar{\nabla}_{\rho}h_{\mu\nu}+\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi^{\rho}h_{\rho\nu}
+\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\xi^{\rho}h_{\mu\rho}
\color{red}{ 
-\bar{\nabla}_{\mu}\big(\xi^{\rho}h_{\rho\nu}\big)
-\bar{\nabla}_{\nu}\big(\xi^{\rho}h_{\mu\rho}\big)
}~, \tag{6}
\end{align}
which agrees with (3) up to terms in red. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but one thought is that I would expect $\xi$ and $h$ to be of the same order. The expressions agree at first order in small quantities but not second order; is it possible you just need to be more careful at keeping all terms at second order for both methods to agree?

Comment: I thought this could possibly be a source of error too, but I can't see where I would get any other mixed second order terms $\thicksim \xi h$. In particular, if I write $\delta g_{\mu\nu}=2\nabla_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}+\mathcal{O}(\xi^2)$ and $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}=\bar{\Gamma}_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}+\delta\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ with $\delta\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}$ defined as in the OP (it's $\thicksim \mathcal{O}(h^1)$.

Comment: Then to second order I find
$$\delta g_{\mu\nu}=2\big(\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}-2\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}\xi_{\rho}\big)+\mathcal{O}(\xi^2)=2\big(\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}-\bar{\Gamma}_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}\xi_{\rho}\big)-2\delta\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\rho}\xi_{\rho}+\mathcal{O}(\xi^2)~.$$
There seems to be no terms other terms $\sim \mathcal{O}(\xi h)$ and no terms at all $\sim \mathcal{O}(h^2)$. For some reason I don't think I should be including terms of second order in only one of the small parameters (i.e. $\xi^2$ or $h^2$). See for example page 48 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3735.

Comment: $\xi_{\mu}$ may be defined as $\xi_{\mu}=g_{\mu\nu}\xi^{\nu}$ and $\overline{\xi}_{\mu}=\overline{g}_{\mu\nu}\xi^{\nu}$. The difference between them is the same as the extra terms in equation (6): $\overline{\nabla}_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}=\overline{\nabla}_{\mu}\overline{\xi}_{\nu}+\overline{\nabla}_{\mu}(h_{\nu\rho}\xi^{\rho})$

Comment: Ah, so I was indeed being careless with the second order quantities. If I keep proper track of this, then equation (3) should read 
$$\delta_{\xi}g_{\mu\nu} = 2\bar{\nabla}_{(\mu}\bar{\xi}_{\nu)}+\mathcal{L}_{\xi}h_{\mu\nu}~,$$
which is equal to (6).  If you write this up as an answer I will accept it. It would be a bonus if you could comment on why we keep terms of order $\mathcal{O}(\xi h)$ but not $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ or $\mathcal{O}(\xi^2)$.